# Incorrect Padding | Nested FlatList Inside SectionList

Tags: react-native, flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I have a SectionList where I have the first and second sections as horizontally scrollable. I've done this by nesting a FlatList inside these sections. However, adding horizontal padding to the FlatList so it starts 16px from the left it also cuts off 16px from the right.

I have tried changing `horizontalPadding: 16` to `paddingLeft: 16` & `paddingStart: 16` however this has the same outcome.

### Illustration below or expected vs actual

[image: visual example]

### Code

```
  <SectionList
    sections={sections}
    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
      const type = section.type;
      switch (type) {
        case "one":
          return (
            <FlatList
              style={{
                paddingHorizontal: 16,
                marginBottom: 16,
              }}
              data={section.data}
              horizontal
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Card1 item={item} />}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                <View style={{ width: 8 }}></View>
              )}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            />
          );
        case "two":
          return (
            <FlatList
              style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 16, marginBottom: 24 }}
              data={section.data}
              horizontal
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Card2 item={item} onPress={offerDetails} />
              )}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                <View style={{ width: 16 }}></View>
              )}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            />
          );
        case "three":
          return (
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 21,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                paddingHorizontal: 16,
                marginBottom: 12,
              }}
            >
              {section.title}
            </Text>
          );
      }
    }}
    renderItem={({ item, section }) => {
      if (section.horizontal) {
        return null;
      }
      return <Card3 item={item} onPress={offerDetails} />;
    }}
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When utilizing the FlatList component, it is possible to apply styles to the scroll view content container by making use of the [contentContainerStyles](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) property. This property allows you to specify styles that will be applied to the container that wraps all of the child views.

Comment: This is the solution, however, on load the content inset at the beginning doesn't add padding so I have added 16 padding at the start with right content inset as 32.